# Can I run an apk in device while the apk is stored on cloud?

Tags: android, apk

Just being curious to know, if it is possible to run any `.apk` file on my device while the apk file is hosted on a cloud server.

Being curious and thinking of an idea, if it happens? Thanks.

Comment: No. You need the physical apk on your device. OR use a Web application (but you'll need to stay connected to use it).

Comment: @DerGolem heard about using Web application for the first time. Could you elaborate a bit more as to how it works and post a few links if possible

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+web+application+tutorial&oq=android+web+application+tutorial&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i64.1190j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: thanks @DerGolem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990295/how-to-get-click-event-of-futuresimple-librarys-floatactionbutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the APK has to be installed to be run, for conventional definitions of the term "run". You can download the APK from "the cloud" and prompt the user to install it, though.

Comment: i  am getting but my plan is that i will develop an app(just like front end) and will store many apk on cloud so that user do not need to install it. he jsut have to install my app.

Comment: @DevendraSingh: That is not possible, sorry. You are welcome to write a Web browser that can browse many Web apps, though.

Comment: why peoples voting down?? isn't it generic question?

Comment: please guide me in this. how can i get UI like this app. [Please check](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxVa3_wqOp_rcEdVNHhzTE0wcWM/view) and this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391167/expand-collapse-cardview-on-scroll-in-android)