# How to get Click Event of futuresimple library's FloatActionButton?

Tags: android

I am using [this library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) this library.I used the code described in its description on github. looks like this I have event for the menu buttons, not its main Button. i want to get its main button's click event for make rest layout blur when its clicked/expended. even want to hide or set its default state  when user click or touch somewhere else on screen.

```
FloatingActionButton actionC = new FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
    actionC.setIcon(R.drawable.notes);
    actionC.setTitle("Add note");
    actionC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //
        }
    });

    FloatingActionsMenu floatingActionsMenu = (FloatingActionsMenu)findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions);
    floatingActionsMenu.addButton(actionC);
   // ((FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_actions)).addButton(actionC);
    final FloatingActionButton actionA = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_a);
    actionA.setIcon(R.drawable.event);
    actionA.setTitle("Make life Event");


    actionA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and the answer is .

```
  floatingActionsMenu.setOnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener(new FloatingActionsMenu.OnFloatingActionsMenuUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuExpanded() {
            Toast.makeText(Launcher.this, "Fdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuCollapsed() {


        }
    });
```